# Toggle Select disable through scope variable angular js 1.2

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm unable to disable select option based a scope variable. Here is the plunker.

Any help is much appreciated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4J7jBQ?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Thats because it's `ng-disabled` not `ng-disable`. Also, remove the `{{}}` when using `$scope` variables in `ng*` attributes, it's already Angular code.

So, in summary: `ng-disabled="setDisabled"` will work.

Comment: I have updated the plunker. It still dosen't work. I think it has something to do with angularjs 1.2 It worked beautifully before I made the update.

Comment: In your controller, your variable is still called "SetDisable", not "SetDisabled". It works if you change it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ng-disabled (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled) and then use a boolean to toggle it on and off. So `ng-disabled="setDisabled"`